# Android.Picasso не загружает картинку Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

Picasso не загружает фотографию и приложение вылетает
Не знаю как решить проблему

```
val userNameTextView = nav_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById<TextView>(R.id.user_profile_name)
userNameTextView.text = Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.name
Picasso.get().load(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImageView)
```

Ошибка в: .load(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.image)

Prevalent.kt

```
import com.example.nerus.Model.Users
class Prevalent {
    companion object {
        lateinit var currentOnlineUser: Users
        const val UserPasswordKey: String = "UserPhone"
        const val UserPhoneKey: String = "UserPassword"
    }
}
```

Users.kt

```
class Users {
    var name: String = ""
    var phone: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    var image: String = ""
    var address: String = ""

    constructor()

    constructor(name: String, phone: String, password: String, image: String, address: String) {
        this.name = name
        this.phone = phone
        this.password = password
        this.image = image
        this.address = address
    }
}
```

Лог с ошибкой

```
2019-05-27 23:04:13.138 30914-30962/com.example.nerus E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x75fe286f40 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x75cecf9798 arg=0x0
2019-05-27 23:04:13.138 30914-30962/com.example.nerus E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x75fe286f40 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
2019-05-27 23:04:14.416 30914-30914/com.example.nerus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nerus, PID: 30914
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nerus/com.example.nerus.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2915)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2980)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1686)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6519)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:974)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)
        at com.example.nerus.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:63)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6715)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2868)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2980) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1686) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6519) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:974)
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.nerus">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
  >
    <activity android:name=".SettinsActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AdminAddNewProductActivity2">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AdminCategoryActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AdminAddNewProductActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignInActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LogInActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"
    />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Было бы не плохо, чтоб Вы прикрепили полный лог ошибки. В манифест не забыли добавить строку <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ?

Comment: Добавил описание

Answer (score 1):

Судя из Вашего лога и сообщения об ошибке "Path must not be empty." - Вы передаёте пустой путь к картинке в методе `load(...)`

в этом участке кода: 
`Picasso.get().load(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImageView)`

Попробуйте задать валидный путь к картинке и у Вас всё получится ;)
Вот пример:
`Picasso.with(context).load("https://square.github.io/picasso/static/sample.png").placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImageView)`